# Drupal 6 editing the submit function on a content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

I have a content type and I wish to edit the submit function. I thought the way you would do this would be as follows:

```
function moduleName_contentType_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    drupal_set_message(t('Test'));
}
```

I cleared the cached but the message is not being displayed on the screen. Am I doing this correctly or do I need to use form_alter? If so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case too you can use form alter, and add

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'your_sumbmit_callback';
```

or if you want to completely change the submit and do your own thing:

```
$form['#submit'] = array('your_submit_callback');
```

And obviously the callback function needs to be defined;

```
function your_submit_callback( $form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('hello');
}
```